# CakePHP 2.x problems with prepending / appending to existing viewblock

Tags: append, prepend, cakephp-2.x

Atm i'm trying to "redesign" the page of my boss to get rid of the quirly nonDRY code.. repeating to add the menu over and over again..

i'm quite "new" to cake but can handle it on an average level i think :)

the problem is..

---

in my layout view i set an

```
$this->start('sidebar');
$this->element('menu');
$this->end();
```

where the menu element is a `<li>` collection

somewhere else i want to add `<li>` elements before and after the menu element so i tried

```
$this->append('menu');
<li>Something</li>
$this->end();
```

to  append and

```
$this->prepend('menu');
<li>Somethingelse</li>
$this->end();
```

to prepend it

well... the `<li>` appear.. but always prepended.. so i guess the problem here is, that the elements get rendered before the layout, which makes sense.. maybe i'm to tired or brainbusted, but how can i fix this up?

any ideas anyone?

Thanks a lot :)

greetings Tobi

Answer (score 0):

I would use only element without that cake strange snippet sharing:

Create file e.g `boss_menu.ctp` in `/View/Elements/` put there all menu content, and when you want to use it write: `<?php echo $this->element('/boss_menu'); ?>` and its done.

But probably creating layout would be better in your case: [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts).